# Spring properties file vs system property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is kind of strange question, but are there any advantages of defining  a variable as system property like,

```
 System.getProperty("files-dir", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/uploaded-files");
```

over defining it inside Spring application properties. What is more preferable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define the property in `application.properties` then your distributable (the JAR or WAR) is self contained and aware of its own configuration regardless of **how** it is run.

If you define the property via the command line (`java -Dxxx=yyy`) then you have to configure whatever it is that runs the distributable (e.g. a web container, a script etc).

In practice you might end up with some combination of both:

- JVM configuration properties (e.g. min, max heap settings) defined outside your distributable
- Application configuration properties (e.g. logs directory, DB connectivity details etc) defined inside your distributable

A common case for defining application properties via the command line is to cater for environment/host specific properties but [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) provides a useful mechanism for defining environment specific properties.

I'd suggest that the starting point should be to define all application specific configuration in Spring property files and to only deviate from this where a compelling reason is found to do so. A common rationale for this is that spreading your application configuration around (some of it in application.properties, some of it in scripts or env files) might make it harder to developer/devops/support teams to understand/enhance/manage/support your application.

Comment: The code is actually written by some other developer. I don't prefer defining the property as system property, and there is not a good reason fro this app to do so either. But I have no any reasoning to claim that this is bad and change it. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added a justification to the answer, see "A common rationale for this is ... "

Answer (score 3):

System properties can be used, but remember that it can affect a different program, and would be useful to consider them as constants (never change), but Spring properties can provide you special configuration for your java application only.

On same host you can run different java applications. If you need different properties for them you can not use system properties (with same names).

Comment: you seems to confuse environment variables and system properties.
in Java the System.getProperties() returns the properties passed to the java command with -D option like: -DmySystemProperty=myValue, so it cannot affect another java application .. instead if they belongs to the same application server..